# is there a way to get a value of a td as a value of "ControlToCompare" in asp compare validator?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Sorry Im a noob. is there a way to get a value of a td (which is outside of a templatefield) as a value of "ControlToCompare" of an asp:CompareValidator? i need to compare a date field to an existing given date. Pls help!
I know this is wrong. but heres my code

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ControlToCompare="<$("#spanDateofInjury span").text()" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom"
     Type="Date" Operator="LessThanEqual" 
    ErrorMessage="From Date should be less than or equal to To Date" 
    runat="server" Display="None" EnableClientScript="true" ValidationGroup="PaymentsDetailUpdate"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: as u can see Im trying to make a jquery code. but this is wrong. or do u thing there are other ways?

Answer (score 0):

As the span is read-only you can try this method. Place a hidden field inside the TemplateField and compare with it like this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDateOfInjury" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToCompare="hdnDateOfInjury" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom"
    Display="None"
    EnableClientScript="true" 
    ErrorMessage="From Date should be less than or equal to To Date"
    Operator="LessThanEqual"
    Type="Date"  
    ValidationGroup="PaymentsDetailUpdate">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```